# How do I access a span inside styled div?

Tags: html, css, ruby, nokogiri

I have HTML like this:

```
<div style = 'display: hidden'>
<span class = "thing">text</span>
</div>

<div style = 'display: block'>
<span class = "thing">text</span>
</div>

<div style = 'display: hidden'>
<span class = "thing">text</span>
</div>
```

I want to only select the `<span>` tags with class "thing" which appear in the unhidden divs. How can I do this with the Nokogiri gem?

This is what I'm trying:

```
page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@url))
item_list = page.css("div[@style != 'display: hidden'] span.thing")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I would do :

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse <<-eotl
<div style = 'display: hidden'> <span class = "thing">text1</span> </div>
<div style = 'display: block'> <span class = "thing">text2</span> </div>
<div style = 'display: hidden'> <span class = "thing">text3</span> </div>
<div style = 'display: foo'> <span class = "thing">text4</span> </div>
eotl

doc.css("div:not([style$=hidden])>span.thing").size # => 2

doc.css("div:not([style$=hidden])>span.thing").each do |tag|
  p [tag.name,tag.text]
end
# >> ["span", "text2"]
# >> ["span", "text4"]
```

Two main CSS Selectors out of others,I would like to introduce to you, as below :

[`:not`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

> Selects all elements that do not match the given selector.

[`[attribute$=value]`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string. The comparison is case sensitive.

Comment: You're going to get roasted for linking to w3schools (see http://w3fools.com/) as they're just trying to sell useless certifications by gaming Google, you might want to find a more reliable reference such as w3.org. Note that w3schools has nothing to do with the real W3.

Comment: Thanks. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS) is also a good reference for CSS.